# How to replace all the regular express from the file with exact matching expressions?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, regex, liquid-layout

I want to replace all the regular expressions from the file.When i convert the html file to .liquid file.It convert all the code to special characters.How to avoid from special characters. And how i can remove all the special characters from the file with accurate one.File is too long.There are many special charachers almost every type.I want to replace all with accurate one.
The code is below:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const script = `<div>Test</div>`

  fs.readFile('product.html', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    data = data.replace(/<html>/g, " ").replace(/<head>/g, " ").replace(/<body>/g, " ")
    data = data.replace(/<\/head>/g, " ").replace(/<\/html>/g, " ").replace(/<\/body>/g, " ")


    fs.writeFile("product.liquid", data, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
      console.log("The file was saved!");
    });

  });
})
```

The read file is :

```
  {% endcomment %}
  {%- assign current_variant = product.selected_or_first_available_variant -%}
  {%- assign product_image_zoom_size = '1024x1024' -%}
  {%- assign product_image_scale = '2' -%}
  {%- assign enable_image_zoom = section.settings.enable_image_zoom -%}
  {%- assign compare_at_price = current_variant.compare_at_price -%}
  {%- assign price = current_variant.price -%}

{
  "name": {
    "da": "Produktsider",
    "de": "Produktseiten",
    "en": "Product pages",
    "es": "Páginas de productos",
    "fi": "Tuotesivut",
    "fr": "Pages de produits",
    "hi": "उत्पाद पेज",
    "it": "Pagine di prodotto",
    "ja": "商品ページ",
    "ko": "제품 페이지",
    "nb": "Produktsider",
    "nl": "Productpagina's",
    "pt-BR": "Páginas de produtos",
    "pt-PT": "Páginas de produtos",
    "sv": "Produktsidor",
    "th": "หน้าสินค้า",
    "zh-CN": "产品页面",
    "zh-TW": "產品頁面"
  }
}
```

Output is :

```
  {%&#45; assign current_variant = product.selected_or_first_available_variant &#45;%}
  {%&#45; assign product_image_zoom_size = &amp;apos;1024x1024&amp;apos; &#45;%}
  {%&#45; assign product_image_scale = &amp;apos;2&amp;apos; &#45;%}
  {%&#45; assign enable_image_zoom = section.settings.enable_image_zoom &#45;%}
  {%&#45; assign compare_at_price = current_variant.compare_at_price &#45;%}
  {%&#45; assign price = current_variant.price &#45;%}

{
  &amp;quot;name&amp;quot;: {
    &amp;quot;da&amp;quot;: &amp;quot;Produktsider&amp;quot;&sbquo;
    &amp;quot;de&amp;quot;: &amp;quot;Produktseiten&amp;quot;&sbquo;
    &amp;quot;en&amp;quot;: &amp;quot;Product pages&amp;quot;&sbquo;
    &amp;quot;es&amp;quot;: &amp;quot;P&amp;&#35;xE1;ginas de productos&amp;quot;&sbquo;
    &amp;quot;fi&amp;quot;: &amp;quot;Tuotesivut&amp;quot;&sbquo;
    &amp;quot;fr&amp;quot;: &amp;quot;Pages de produits&amp;quot;&sbquo;
    &amp;quot;hi&amp;quot;: &amp;quot;&amp;&#35;x909;&amp;&#35;x924;&amp;&#35;x94D;&amp;&#35;x92A;&amp;&#35;x93E;&amp;&#35;x926; &amp;&#35;x92A;&amp;&#35;x947;&amp;&#35;x91C;&amp;quot;&sbquo;
    &amp;quot;it&amp;quot;: &amp;quot;Pagine di prodotto&amp;quot;&sbquo;
    &amp;quot;ja&amp;quot;: &amp;quot;&amp;&#35;x5546;&amp;&#35;x54C1;&amp;&#35;x30DA;&amp;&#35;x30FC;&amp;&#35;x30B8;&amp;quot;&sbquo;
    &amp;quot;ko&amp;quot;: &amp;quot;&amp;&#35;xC81C;&amp;&#35;xD488; &amp;&#35;xD398;&amp;&#35;xC774;&amp;&#35;xC9C0;&amp;quot;&sbquo;
    &amp;quot;nb&amp;quot;: &amp;quot;Produktsider&amp;quot;&sbquo;
    &amp;quot;nl&amp;quot;: &amp;quot;Productpagina&amp;apos;s&amp;quot;&sbquo;
    &amp;quot;pt&#45;BR&amp;quot;: &amp;quot;P&amp;&#35;xE1;ginas de produtos&amp;quot;&sbquo;
    &amp;quot;pt&#45;PT&amp;quot;: &amp;quot;P&amp;&#35;xE1;ginas de produtos&amp;quot;&sbquo;
    &amp;quot;sv&amp;quot;: &amp;quot;Produktsidor&amp;quot;&sbquo;
    &amp;quot;th&amp;quot;: &amp;quot;&amp;&#35;xE2B;&amp;&#35;xE19;&amp;&#35;xE49;&amp;&#35;xE32;&amp;&#35;xE2A;&amp;&#35;xE34;&amp;&#35;xE19;&amp;&#35;xE04;&amp;&#35;xE49;&amp;&#35;xE32;&amp;quot;&sbquo;
    &amp;quot;zh&#45;CN&amp;quot;: &amp;quot;&amp;&#35;x4EA7;&amp;&#35;x54C1;&amp;&#35;x9875;&amp;&#35;x9762;&amp;quot;&sbquo;
    &amp;quot;zh&#45;TW&amp;quot;: &amp;quot;&amp;&#35;x7522;&amp;&#35;x54C1;&amp;&#35;x9801;&amp;&#35;x9762;&amp;quot;
  }&sbquo;
```

How to check all the regular expressions and replace all ?

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are asking. Are you trying to not use the regular expression in the function?

I think it would be helpful if you also provided the (input + desired output) tuples.

Comment: you need to specify all characters that you consider special in this case. Also I have to agree with the previous commenter that it is unclear what you want to achieve. Perhaps you could state clearly the original file and an example of what you want it to look like after all the replacements?